# Android x86 Won't boot up

Tags: boot, android-x86, virtualbox

I am trying to install Android-x86 6.0 marshmallow on Oracle Virtual Box. I was experiencing difficulty installing, but I read elsewhere to change the grub from `android_x86` to `x86`, which I did with little to no difficulty, and successfully installed it.

On bootup, it gives the message: `Failed to find cpu0 device node`, but it keeps going. When it gets to the A N D R O I D message, it stops, unlike all the tutorials floating around on the internet.

[image]

I am a total beginner to android, so help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a little further by using Grubs 'edit, e' key and adding `debug DEUBG=1`

That will give you a linux shell, and kernel debug messages.

Also, you can force by choosing the resident option and replacing `USB_PARTITION=1` with `INSTALL=2`

http://support.jide.com/hc/en-us/articles/222974048-How-to-install-Remix-OS-for-PC-single-boot-on-hard-disk-

Answer (score 0):

You must choose to install grub with the system.

In the grub menu press 'e' to edit the boot command, press 'e' again to edit the first command which starts with "kernel".
 Append this:

```
 nomodeset
```

to the and of the command and press Enter to save, finally press 'b' to boot from the modified command and it will boot up successfully.

I tried this with CM 14.1 and Android 7.1 images and it works after I had the same problem with VMWare Workstation 14.